# ADF Tester Model not load

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am working with JDeveloper 12.2.1 and when I try to run the Application Module to test the view object instance the ADF tester model windows does not load. Here a print screen:

[image]

The ADF tester windows appear only when there is not any view object instance in the data model. Can you help explain why this is or resolve it? I can not work or test the application module.

Comment: Are you able to run any other Application module with a view object in it? you could try this by re-creating a simple view object and see if your AM works with that - the problem could be with your view object (bad query or some other issue)

Comment: Thanks Jang-Vijay i solved the problem it was wrong in some View object query